# @JSName / @JsExport in common folder

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I am actually working in a Kotlin Multiplatform Project where we developed common code for Android / IOS / Web

However due to JS, some classes in `common/` need to be annotated with `@JSName / @JsExport`.

Do you think is a good practice to have these annotations in `common/`. Would not be better to use `actual / expect` feature to avoid having `@JSName / @JsExport` in `common/` classes